# Properly configuring signal.setitimer()

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, setitimer

I'm having a bad time figuring why the program is pausing indefinitely, i.e. exhibiting infinite-loop-like behavior

```
def class foo():
    '''
    ...
    '''
    def __catcher(self, signum, _):
        print "TIME OUT EXCEEDED"
        # Reset timer
        signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.0, _SENDERTMOUT_)
        # Do something 
        for i in range (self.base, self.next_seqno):
            '''
            ...
            '''
    def start(self):
        while something:
            '''
            Start doing some work
            '''
            if self.base == self.next_seqno:
                old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.__catcher) 
                signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, _SENDERTMOUT_)

            '''
            Do more work until timer goes off
            '''
```

Perhaps I don't know the sequence of execution, when timer times out in start(), the program jumps to __catcher(), right? Then timer is reset, and the rest of the statement, **then where does the program resume execution**?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it gets back to the place the timer interrupted?